# Writing (adding) the label and values of vertical lines on second x axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am manually adding some vertical line in my plot

```
plt.axvline(x=115,color='b')
plt.axvline(x=2*115,color='g')
plt.axvline(x=3*115,color='r')
plt.axvline(x=4*115,color='c')
```

I want to know that how can to use the values of this lines in second x axis (x axis at the top)?
We have values of another component on x axis at the bottom.

thank you

Comment: "I want to know that how can to use the values of this lines in second x axis (x axis at the top)?"... This statement is highly unclear. You need to elaborate what you want to achieve. What do you mean by "use the values of this lines"? What values? Do you want vertical lines on the top x-axis?

Comment: What do you mean by values of this line ?

Comment: @Sheldore  Sorry if it is vague. I have several vertical line. I want instead of typing by hand on image, with python put the value of each vertical line on the top of the plotting box or in the x axis on the top. we have two x axis, one is at the bottom  another one at the top and for y axis one in left and one in right

Comment: @abhilb the value of x axi that those line are appeare. for example one one them is on `x=3` for all values of `y` axis. i want to write this value at the top exactly above the each vertical line